# Compiling with mxmlc vs Flash

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, adobe

I have some ActionScript code that I got from some website. I've tried to compile the code and it seems to have compiled with no errors. However, it doesn't work as expected and I am wondering how I can debug this?

It seems that the website uses Flash to compile it because there's a .fla file located as well. Does anyone have any idea?

Forgot to mention that I am on Unix and will be compiling on Solaris.

Comment: The Fla file will be required for the app to work.

Comment: show me the as code please.if there are no libraries used from fla, we could run it, or even w/o them too.

Comment: Here's the link to the source: 

http://github.com/mediafront/osmplayer/tree/

Answer (score 1):

Download Flash demo version and find out! The .fla may contain some assets or even had some code, I don't know of any other ways to compile the .fla!